# Python multiprocessing function with args as constant value

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a function with takes constant arguments.
I'm want to use all my cpu cores to run the funtion.

```
def func(s3_bucket, client, start_date, end_date):
  ........
  ........
```

suppose the values of the args are -

```
s3_bucket = 'foo'
client= 'bar'
start_date= '2019-05-02'
end_date= '2020-05-02'
```

I tried partial and pool.map but it is of no use as map requires iterable. 
I dont want to change my func either.

The method that I tried is -

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

with Pool(os.cpu_count()-1) as pool:
    func_call = partial(func, s3_bucket, client, start_date, end_date)
    result_dict = pool.map(func_call,range(1))
```

I'd be glad if somebody helped me with this.

Comment: A single function call is essentially indivisible. `Pool` has no idea how to split up whatever work might be going on *inside* the function call across multiple processes. It's still your job to decompose `func` into jobs that *can* be executed in parallel.

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to do - your function takes four arguments yet you are creating a *partial* using all four arguments. Take a look at this example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers